# How create a grid layout with paper-card

Tags: css, polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to mix the [template repeater](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates) and [the paper-card tutorial](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-card/demo/demo/index.html) in the Polymer Starter Kit.

My aim is to copy that kind of grid : 
[image]
<sub>(source: [instantshift.com](http://cdn.instantshift.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/material-design-01.jpg))</sub>

I created two custom elements :

1. A list of employees
2. An employee

Employee List:

```
<style is="custom-style">
#board {
  @apply(--layout-vertical);           <<= HERE ARE DEFINED THE LAYOUT OF THE GRID
  @apply(--layout-wrap);
  height: 344px;
  width: 384px;
}
#board > paper-card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 184px;
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
</style>
  <template>
    <div id="board">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employeesArray}}">
          <employee-element name="{{item.title}}"
                           preview="{{item.preview}}"
                           width={{item.width}} height={{item.height}}>
          </employee-element>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Employee :

```
<paper-card
  heading="{{name}}"
  image="{{preview}}"
  style="max-width:{{width}}px;
         max-height:{{height}}px;"
  >
  <div class="card-actions">
    <paper-icon-button class="favorite" icon="favorite"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button class="bookmark" icon="bookmark"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button class="share" icon="social:share"></paper-icon-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Here is what I get :

[image]

How can I approach the result expected ? Is there a setting making the card arranging themselves automatically ?

How can I get a "carriage return"-like behaviour ?

---

**Answer results** (thanks to @Snekw) :

Steps :

Add the following line where you import your elements (elements/elements.html in my case)

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
```

My Employee list element now looks like :

```
<style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex">
    .flex-wrap {
      @apply(--layout-horizontal);
      @apply(--layout-wrap);
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <div class="container flex-wrap">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employeesArray}}">
          <employee-element name="{{item.title}}"
                           preview="{{item.preview}}"
                           width={{item.width}} height={{item.height}}>
          </employee-element>

      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
```

And I get this result :

[image]

I still have to fix the problem with the paper-card action panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `iron-flex` class on your `style` tag.

```
<style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex">
//your styling
</style>
```

You will need to load the `iron-flex-layout-classes.html` element. Iron-flex-layout element contains the `--layout-vertical` and `--layout-wrap` properties.

More on iron-flex-layout here: [iron-flex-layout-classes GitHub](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout-classes.html)